# Multiple URL structures in Wordpress using Ngninx

Tags: wordpress, nginx, seo

So I have a strange project I'm trying to do.

I have currently two websites for the same entity, on that lives at the base domain, and one that lives at blog.domain.com.

I want to have the following structure in one Wordpress installation:

- [**domain.com**] goes to a particular page in the Wordpress install
- [**blog.domain.com**] goes to the default post list page
- [**domain.com/blog**] goes to the same post list page

All the individual post pages should be accessible via:

- **blog.domain.com**/post_url
- **domain.com/post**/post_url

Ultimately the idea is to phase out the blog subdomain, but keeping it around for SEO purposes.

From what I've researched so far, this can't be done with Wordpress alone, but I'm using Nginx as the web server, and it seems powerful enough to do this.

Is this a good idea, or am I going to shoot myself in the foot?

Comment: nginx can certainly do the various rewrites/proxy_pass, however unless you're going to post-process the content, isn't Wordpress going to output the URLS that it believes the content is at?

Comment: Yeah, but that would not be a problem. For Wordpress everything would be in the new "structure". Nginx would just rewrite the requests from blog.domain.com to domain.com/blog. I'm just not sure if nginx is actually capable of this, and if this impacts SEO in any bad way

Comment: Is the "real" location one of those domains, or is there an internal IP that both would send to (i.e. proxy_pass) ?

Comment: @jdewald I'm thinking that both domains would point to the same IP (Nginx) and internally there's also just one instance of WordPress. I'm creating a test environment to figure this all out.